# What tense are used in these sentences with construction “it has been”?

Tags: grammar, tense

Sentences:

1. And it has been a pleasure watching you soar.
2. Financially it has been a great move.
3. At best it has been a slow recovery.
4. Overall it has been a difficult weekend.
5. So it has been a seamless transition.
6. And it has been a lot of hard work getting him back to health.
7. But it has been a struggle for them to maintain profitability.
8. Still, it has been a terrific season for Arizona.

I don't understand, are there Present Perfect or Perfect Continuous or other? For perfect I don't see some result of action. For perfect continuous I don't see -ing at the end of the verb. Am I right understand that “it has been” in all these sentences almost equal “it was”? Can you give me a link where this grammatical construction (it has been) is explained in detail (example of using)?

Answer (score 1):

They are all present perfect.

In the present tense these sentence would be:

1. It is a pleasure watching you soar

That is a copular sentence with a dummy subject meaning "Watching you soar is a pleasure".  That sentence refers to a present state.

The present perfect means that the state (of pleasure) continued until the present. The meaning, without the dummy subject is:

> Watching you soar has been a pleasure (since you started soaring until now).

So you might use 1. when you are saying goodbye to a colleague who began as a junior intern and was very successful at work and "soared" up the corporate hierarchy.  The state of *pleasure at watching them soar* has continued until the present.

The same reasoning applies to all the others.